# Pywin32 - how to access the data that a "data handle" refers to

Tags: python, pywin32, handles

I'm trying to gather information about some child windows in a Windows application (written in Visual Studio using C++). I'm using `pywinauto` and `pywin32`.

In a very small python script, I thought I would get good information using `win32gui.EnumPropsEx`. There is less information returned than I hoped, and one of the items returned is supposed to be a "handle to the property data". Once I have the "handle", how do I access the property data?

Here's the code:

```
import win32gui

def propfunc(hwnd, prop, x, y):
    print("\nProperty for %d is %s\n" %(hwnd, prop))
    print("x is %d, and y is %s\n" %(x, y))
    return 1

def main():
    handleList = (1574574, 722384, 1311872, 1967920, 2295590)
    for hwnd in handleList:
        print("For hwnd %d:" %hwnd)
        win32gui.EnumPropsEx(hwnd, propfunc, None)
        print("\n\n\n")

main()
```

And here's a(n edited) snippet of the result I get:

```
For hwnd 1574574:

Property for 1574574 is fpTextTip

x is 2621596, and y is None

Property for 1574574 is 43288

x is -1, and y is None
```

I'm thinking the `2621596` is the "handle to the property data" that I was told to expect. I have no clue about how to retrieve that property data, and msdn has not been helpful. Anyone care to tell me how one gets from a data handle to the data?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with pywinauto? `app.window(handle=hwnd, top_level_only=False).wrapper_object()` In what form do you expect the property data? Which properties do you expect to see?

Comment: Vasily Ryabov - I haven't figured out how to get any information about the contents of these child windows -- the spreadsheets I had foolishly hoped to find some way to access. Didn't expect to find anything of real value in these properties; just grasping at straws.
Since neither pywinauto nor pywin32 (just a 'wrapper' around Windows functions, right?) recognizes any other 'children' of these spreadsheet (child) windows -- where I had hoped to find references to the contained cells -- I am at a loss how to proceed. Some cells respond to input and clicks. Windows must know about them!!

Comment: First you need to try Spy++ and Inspect.exe (they are mentioned in [this guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) with download links). If Inspect.exe can't see the UI elements, then it's time to give up. Not earlier.

Comment: Vasily Ryabov - Yeah, Inspect.exe and Spy++ did not provide any additional information:
How found: Mouse move (1391,188)
 hwnd=0x00090A6A 32bit class="SPR32AU80_SpreadSheet" 
ChildId: 0
Interfaces: IEnumVARIANT IOleWindow IAccIdentity
Impl: Remote oleacc proxy
...
ChildCount: 2
Window: 0x90A6A
FirstChild: [null]
LastChild: [null]
Next: [null]
Previous: [null]
...
Other Props: Object has no additional properties
Children: none : window : invisible,focusable
 none : window : invisible,focusable
Ancestors: "Mode: " : window : focusable
 "" : dialog : focusable
...